# output from expect is not complete

Tags: linux, shell, expect, rsync

I have this script in order to make rsync with another server, the propossal is to get arround 1600 files, this script as two variables, date and hour, so, I send these two values with shell script then I pass the values.

Expect script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set DIR_DATE [lrange $argv 0 0]
# Define date variable.

set DT_HOUR [lrange $argv 1 1]
# Define hour variable.

spawn rsync -avzb -e ssh user@IPSERVER:/SOURCE_DIR/$DIR_DATE/A$DIR_DATE.$DT_HOUR*.txt /TARGET_DIR/$DIR_DATE/
expect "password:"
send "PASSWORD\r"
#interact
expect eof
```

And the shell script is:

```
#!/bin/bash

***HERE is the code to get date and hour variable: DT_DATE,DT_HOUR; then, next step is run the expect script***

${DIR_BIN}/rsync_expect.sh ${DT_DATE} ${DT_HOUR}
```

You can note, in the expect script, I comment "interactive" word, because:

1. If it is not comment and run manually the script, it runs very well, it get 1600 files.
2. If it is commented, and run through the shell script, it only get arround 50 files and that's off.

So, any sugestion in order to get all files using shell scripts?

Comment: Is the question why, without interact, the script is exiting early? That's probably an expect timeout. Try setting an unlimited (or at least longer) timeout.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably timing out: 50 files is probably what you can transfer in (default) 10 seconds. Add this before you spawn: `set timeout -1`

".sh" is a bad file extension for an expect script: use ".exp"

The `lrange` command returns a *list*. Use `lassign $argv DIR_DATE DT_HOUR`

Comment: Thanks Glenn,I made that changes that you sugested, but, when I use "set timeout -1", never start. Only the message Password, then, only the prompt is flashing.

Comment: Are the files being transferred then? You probably don't see anything because you're not `expect`ing anything. Best best is probably to use `interact` if you want to watch the world go past.